# Starling mouseover detection

Tags: actionscript-3, hover, mouseover, starling-framework

I'm making a point & click game where is clickable objects. When player moves mouse over the object, there appear a tooltip beside the cursor. It works almost as intended with the code below:

```
 private  function added():void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED, added);
            this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
        }

protected function onTouch(e:TouchEvent):void
        {
            var touchHover:Touch = e.getTouch(this, TouchPhase.HOVER);

            if (touchHover)
            {
                trace("show");
                //mouse is hovered over this object. Therefore call Hovertext:
                if (Game.hoverText.message != name_)
                    Game.hoverText.message = name_
            }
            else
            {
                //mouse leaves the object
                trace("hide");
                Game.hoverText.hideMessage(name_);
            }

        }
```

However, it has a strange problem I don't understand. If I move mouse over object and then move it downwards still staying over the object, it triggers hiding function in every second frame or so. Same thing happens when I move cursor to the right, but not when moving it up or left.

So my question is what is wrong with my code? Is this even the best way to go to detect when mouse rolls over object and when it rolls away?

EDIT: I have been going through following iterations with each of them the same problem:

```
var touch:Touch = event.getTouch(this);

        if (touch == null) {
            // Set Object alpha to 0;
            //trace("pois");
            Game.hoverText.hideMessage(name_);
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.HOVER) {
            // Set Object alpha to 1;
            //trace("paalla");
            if (Game.hoverText.message != name_)
                Game.hoverText.message = name_;
        }
        else {
            // for a phase BEGIN/MOVE/STATIONARY case
            // see if the touch is over the bounds of the tile (assuming 'this' is the tile)
            HELPER_POINT.x = touch.globalX;
            HELPER_POINT.y = touch.globalY;
            this.globalToLocal(HELPER_POINT, HELPER_POINT);
            if(this.hitTest(HELPER_POINT, true) != null)
            {
                // Set Object alpha to 1; over tile
                trace("paalla");
            }
            else
            {
                // Set Object alpha to 0; not over tile
                trace("pois");
            }
```

### }

```
var touchHover:Touch = e.getTouch(this);

        if (touchHover && touchHover.phase == TouchPhase.HOVER)
        {
            trace("show");
            //mouse is hovered over this object. Therefore call Hovertext:
            if (Game.hoverText.message != name_)
                Game.hoverText.message = name_
        }

        if (touchHover == null)
        {
            //mouse leaves the object
            trace("hide");
            Game.hoverText.hideMessage(name_);
        }
```

Also here is swf for demonstating the problem:
http://www.students.tut.fi/~salmi26/ScorpionBox.html

Comment: I need you to show the code where you attach your event listeners.

Comment: I edited in "added" function which is called when object is added to the stage.

Comment: Try using `TouchPhase.BEGAN` instead of `TouchPhase.HOVER`. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Isn't BEGAN phase used when one wants to detect mouse press? "TouchPhase.BEGAN: The finger touched the screen just now, or the mouse button was pressed." http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/touch_events

Answer (score 0):

```
private function isPressed(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    var touch:touch = event.getTouch(this);

    if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN){
      trace("show");
      //mouse is hovered over this object. Therefore call Hovertext:
      if (Game.hoverText.message != name_)
        Game.hoverText.message = name_
    } else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED){
        trace("release");

        //stop doing stuff
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onButtonHold);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get it working at all. And Starling wiki seems to say that the BEGAN is used only for presses etc. not hovering. I'll look into it more soon though.

Comment: Are you using mouse or real touches?

Comment: I'm using mouse at the moment.

Comment: You have to use Mouse event listeners and MouseEvents instead. It's gonna work then.

Answer (score 0):

```
import starling.events.Touch;
import starling.events.TouchEvent;
import starling.events.TouchPhase;

private var touches:Vector.<Touch>;
private var touch:Touch;
private var touchStage:Touch;

private function onTouch(e:TouchEvent=null):void {

        touches= e.getTouches(DisplayObject(e.target));
        if (touches.length == 1)
        {
            touch = touches[0];

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN){
                m_TouchTarget = touch.target;
                //HERE IS A MOUSE DOWN
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED){
                m_TouchEndedPoint = new Point(touch.globalX, touch.globalY);

                    if (stage.hitTest(m_TouchEndedPoint, true) == m_TouchTarget)
                    {
                        //HERE IS A MOUSE UP
                    }
            }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.MOVED){
                m_TouchEndedPoint = new Point(touch.globalX, touch.globalY);
                //HERE IS A MOUSE OUT

                    if (stage.hitTest(m_TouchEndedPoint, true) != m_TouchTarget)
                    {
                        //HERE IS A MOUSE OVER
                    }
            }

        }
    }
```